# Can't reach Firebase from server behind firewall

Tags: .net, json, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying next code:

```
var fbApp = FirebaseApp.GetInstance("SomeName");
var messaging = FirebaseMessaging.GetMessaging(fbApp);
var result = await messaging.SendAsync(messageToSend, cancellationToken);
```

It works OK, when firewall is not working, otherwise I get next error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.TokenRequestExtenstions.ExecuteAsync(TokenRequest request, HttpClient httpClient, String tokenServerUrl, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IClock clock)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.RefreshTokenAsync()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.ResultWithUnwrappedExceptions[T](Task`1 task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.<>c.<GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync>b__10_0(Task`1 task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(String authUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential.InterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.SendAndReadAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.SendAndDeserializeAsync[TResult](HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingClient.SendAsync(Message message, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendAsync(Message message, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendAsync(Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I use special HttpClientFactory which creates handler with proxy support and add it in **ServiceAccountCredential** and

**AppOptions**

Comment: What does your initialization code look like?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in proxy server. It responded with HTML page in case of any errors, so library couldn't parse unexpected result.